# SQL Query for Case statement of adding Year +1 to display in another column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table in which I have all the values except one column "Year".

I want to display the Year using the values in first column "Code"

For example:

```
Code
195010
195020
195070
195110
195120
195170

Year
Null
Null
Null
Null
NUll
Null
```

What I want to display in the "Year" Column is the following:

```
1950
1950
1951
1951
1951
1952
```

First four numbers representing year and where-ever the code have an ending number of 70 I want to display the first four Number + 1 year added.

I am using the following statement:
case when Code Like N'%70' then N'SHOWYEAR' else substring(Code,1,4) end as 'Year'

I don't know how to put the calculation. I know in my query the SHOWYEAR needs to be changed but can't figure out how to find a way around it.

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server 2012 and greater:

```
SELECT 
    Code, 
    case 
        when Code Like N'%70' 
        then TRY_CONVERT(INT, substring(Code,1,4)) + 1 
        else TRY_CONVERT(INT, substring(Code,1,4)) 
    end as [Year]
from 
    (values ('195010'),('195020'),('195070'),('195110'),('19wrong5120'),('195170')) AS x(Code);
```

Output:

```
code        Year
----------- -----------
195010      1950
195020      1950
195070      1951
195110      1951
19wrong5120 NULL
195170      1952
```

Comment: K - Tried your query and getting the following error:  'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: It seems that you are using sql server lower than 2012. You can use simple CONVERT and manually check wrong strings.

Comment: Thanks my query actually works now:  case when tl.Code Like N'%70' then CONVERT(INT, substring(tl.Code,1,4)) + 1 else CONVERT(INT, substring(tl.Code,1,4)) end as 'AcademicYear', Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If CODE has always the same length(6), you can use following query.  It should work on both db (mysql and MSSQL).  I use a subselect to show you better how it works.  But you can easily do it without a subselect, if you want.
Or course, you could add some checks if CODE can have different formats/values.

```
SELECT A.CODE
       , A.C_YEAR + CASE WHEN C_VALUE = '70' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C_YEAR
FROM (SELECT LEFT(CODE,4) AS C_YEAR, RIGHT(CODE,2) AS C_VALUE, CODE 
      FROM YOURTABLE) A
```

Comment: Thanks etsa, Your query worked as well and was quiet formative. Great.